# How do I extract a substring that follows a specific keyword in R?

Tags: r, regex

I would like to extract people's names that come after the words "Administering Provider". The name could be composed of first, middle, and last name (sometimes just first and last). Also if there's a person title after their name e.g.: Dr. I'm not interested in it

```
df <- data.frame("id"= c(12, 19, 20), 'comments' = c('APK COMMENTS FOR APK LOG ID (145991): APK ADMINISTERING PROVIDER: LAURA ABE LE\rAPK ORDERING PROVIDER: EMMA COURTIER (CMS:19928)',
                                               'APK LOG ID (45664705): APK Administering Provider: CHASITY MCDANIELS (1972609856:0000034)\rAPK ORDERING PROVIDER: PAUL LAMAR (19785663:19928476)',
                                               'APK ADMINISTERING PROVIDER: JOHN DOE, R.N. (EPIC:107080)\rAPK ORDERING PROVIDER: OHM LOHAN (EPIC:1987)'))
```

Below is my attempt to to the solution, but clearly it isn't working:

```
updated.df <- df %>% 
  mutate(name = sub(".ADMINISTERING PROVIDER:", "", comments, ignore.case = T),
         name = trimws(gsub("[(].*$","", comments, ignore.case = T), which = c('both', 'left', 'right')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cut away the irrelevant information before and after using `sub()`. The latter would be either "," for the academic degree, "(" for what seems to be an ID or the special character "\r". If you encounter different cases you should add them into the pattern argument of the second `sub()` call.

```
library(tidyverse)

df$comments %>%
  sub(pattern = ".*ADMINISTERING PROVIDER: ",
      replacement = "", 
      x = ., ignore.case = TRUE) %>%
  sub(pattern = ",.*| \\(.*|\r.*", 
      replacement = "",
      x = .)
```

Comment: It doesnt't seem to be a good idea to remove the literal anchoring part first...

Comment: That took care of my problem. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You can `str_extract` the names, using `(?i)` to make the match case-insensitive and positive look-behind (`(?<=...)`) to assert that the match must be preceded by "Administering provider: ". The actual matching part is expressed in the character class `[\\w ]+` that includes both (*and only*) alphanumeric characters (`\\w`)  and the whitespace   (note that `\\s` will not work here as this character class includes `\r`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$comments, "(?i)(?<=ADMINISTERING PROVIDER:\\s)[\\w ]+")
[1] "LAURA ABE LE"       "CHASITY MCDANIELS " "JOHN DOE"
```

Comment: This could definitely be an alternative solution. Thanks so much